# iOS Segue ViewController Caching

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

In my iOS 5 project, using ARC and Storyboards, I feel that I have run into a strange behavior. I would like to confirm if what I am experiencing is in fact the default behavior AND if it can be modified.

I have a `NavigationController` with a `RootViewController` in story board. Neither of these is tied to a specific subclass. On `RootViewController` I have a button that is connected to a segue for a `ListingViewController`, which makes a static call to a web service (does not vary by user input). What I have noticed - at least in the simulator - is that when I press the button, go back, and press it again, the second time it loads unrealistically quickly! It seems as though the `ListingViewController` is being cached.

Is this supposed to be happening? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: `UIStoryboard` will cache view controllers. If you want an action to happen every time the view controller is displayed, you'll have to do it in `viewWillAppear` as mention in Caleb's answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this supposed to be happening? What can I do to fix it?

Why do you think it's broken? I haven't looked into whether the storyboard holds onto its view controllers, but it wouldn't be surprising if it does.

If you're doing something like making your web service request in `-viewDidLoad`, but you want it to happen every time the view appears, you should move that to `-viewWillAppear` or `-viewDidAppear`.